# Wake on Lan works on one adapter, but not another in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wake-on-lan

I have two NICS, one of them built into the mobo (ASUS).

WOL works when sending the magic packet to the mobo NIC, but not the other.

They both appear to be Realtek adapters, and I've compared all the properties for both with the device manager.  I've used Wireshark and can tell the NIC with the issues is receiving the magic packet.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot/fix this annoying issue?

Comment: confirm that they are the same model and use the same driver. WOL support varies widely between devices and drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try different ports for the magic pakets.

While most Cards listen to both Port 7 and 9, some NICs just work with one or the other.
Note: some available WOL tools on the internet also only send the Magic Pakets on Port 7 or 9

(be sure to send the correct MAC for the specific Card with the packets...)